# How to identify a fragment is called from which fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, listitem

It's more like a conceptual question. Actually i have three fragments let's say A,B and C all are hosted in same activity. Fragment A and B are having List. In both fragments , on click of list item i am loading Fragment C. Now how to identify whether Fragment C is loaded from Fragment A or Fragment B ? I have to make changes in Fragment C's UI when it is loaded on click of any list item in Fragment A.

Comment: What changes need to be made?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to detect clicks in Fragment A and B. In their OnClickListeners, you could create two different setup methods for Fragment C.

Answer (score 0):

> on click of list item i am loading Fragment C

Since it's you who handles the click, simply add whatever you want to make other elements recognize the source of the click. Yet, I'd still say this is wrong approach - you should not really care what fragment it was literlay but rather, assuming fragments A, B reflect different data types, what data type it was. But still - you need to add that data to your bundle (or whatever you use to pass the data to fragment C)